# Are the servers still online for Command and Conquer Generals?

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals, command-and-conquer-zero-hour

Command and Conquer Generals is offered on the Humble Bundle this week, but are the servers still online for it if the game is purchased through Origin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C&C Online](http://cnc-online.net/) still hosts servers for this game. Not that many players online (not even a single game running), but there is something that works. According to the site:

> C&C:Online supports all 5 Command and Conquer titles affected by the GameSpy server shutdown.

So it seems you are pretty safe for the games to be online.

A screenshot from the site (I just made one) below:

[image: C&C Generals screenshot]